# Unsupervised learning examples in Matlab

Tags: classification, matlab, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to classify ECG data into abnormal and normal using unsupervised learning methods in Matlab. The problem is that whilst I am used to supervised learning algorithms, I have never seen how unsupervised neural networks look like in Matlab. Anyone with advice on what first steps I should take, what are the best features to extract, a tutorial or even any example of such a network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-Means (week-8) from Andrew Ng's Machine Learning class. exp7.pdf explains the example exercise and exp7 folder has the matlab codes.

https://github.com/hrzafer/machine-learning-class

https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture

if this is usefull for you please choose my answer bc i dont have any points : )